# iOS - Frosted Glass (iOS 7 Blur) Effect For custom background in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I used a translucent custom image as a UINavigationBar background by calling:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tbg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The navigation bar become translucent but loses Frosted Glass effect. Everything under navigation bar is clear.  Is there a way to add the blur effect?